# jQuery Mansonry plugin doesn't re-render when combined with media queries

Tags: css, responsive-design, fluid-layout, dynamic-columns

What i want to do is achieve IE8+ responsive mansonry layout based on fluid column widths.

When website is rendered mansonry works fine, but after resizing window - media query comes to an action and tells that columns now should be 50%, 50% instead of 25%,25%,25%,25%. Mansonry doesn't work after resizing the window.

I would like to avoid writing calculations in JavaScript.

**Working example**
[Codepen Demo](http://codepen.io/antraxis/pen/pvapEP?editors=110)

**html**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/masonry/3.2.2/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>

<div class="container js-masonry">
  <div class="item">item 1</div>
  <div class="item">item 2</div>
  <div class="item wide-2">item3 wide-2</div>
  <div class="item">item 4</div>
  <div class="item wide-2 tall-2">item 5 wide-2 tall-2</div>
  <div class="item">item 6</div>
  <div class="item">item 7</div>
  <div class="item">item 8</div>
  <div class="item">item 9</div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.item {
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  outline: solid 1px white;
  &.wide-2,
  &.tall-2 {
    background: gray;
  }
  &.tall-2 {
    height: 100px;
  }
}
@media (max-width : 500px){
  .item {
    background: green;
    width: 50%;
    &.wide-2 {
      width: 100%;
    }
  }
}
@media (min-width : 501px){
  .item {
    background: blue;
    width: 25%;
    &.wide-2 {
      width: 50%;
    }
  }
}
```

[image: grid1]
[image: grid2]